# Proof of Theorem 1.19 in Folland: why use completeness of $\mu$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm currently studying measure theory from Folland's textbook, and I have one small question about the proof of theorem 1.19. The theorem states that for any $E\subset\mathbb R$, the following are equivalent:

1. $E$ is $\mu$-measurable.
2. $E=V\setminus N_1$, where $V\in G_\delta$ and $N_1$ is a null set.
3. $E=H\cup N_2$, where $H\in F_\sigma$ and $N_2$ is a null set.

Here, $\mu$ is an arbitrary complete Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure. The bit I'm particularly confused about is when Folland shows that 2 and 3 imply 1, where he invokes the completeness of $\mu$. Why does $\mu$ need to be complete? Aren't $V$ and $H$ Borel sets and hence immediately $\mu$-measurable for any Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $\mu$, complete or not? I'm worried that I'm not understanding something about the completeness of $\mu$ here or that I'm completely overlooking some subtle detail. Thanks!

Comment: In the case of (3), we can write $E = (E \setminus H) \sqcup H$. Consider $E \setminus H$. Then this is a subset of $N_2$ (note it is not exactly $N_2$, since it is possible that $N_2 \cap H \neq \varnothing$). If the measure is complete, then this is measurable, so $E$ is measurable. If the measure is not complete, this may fail.

Comment: Yes, Borel sets are measurable, so the importance of *completeness* lies in the "extra part" (a subset of a set of measure zero) being excluded (2) or included (3).

Answer (score 1):

Its about terminology. In many books of measure theory its said that a set $E$ is $\mu$-measurable when $E$ is measurable respect to the complete $\sigma $-algebra generated by $\mu$. Then we can talk about measurability of sets respect to a measure without explicit mention to an specific $\sigma $-algebra, as the $\sigma $-algebra where $\mu$ is complete is maximal.